# Use smtpd.PureProxy with HTTP proxy

Tags: python, proxy, smtp, http-proxy

I want to set up SMTP relay server which also needs to use HTTP proxy. I'm using Python.

SMTP proxy:

```
import smtpd
import asyncore
smtpd.PureProxy(('local host name', 1234), ('smtp server name', 25))
asyncore.loop()
```

The issue is I need to use HTTP proxy in order to connect to SMTP server.

How can I specify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [desproxy](http://www.google.com.sg/search?q=desproxy) to HTTP tunnel SMTP connection.

Answer (score 0):

Square peg in round hole.  SMTP is a different protocol to HTTP, they are incompatible.

Comment: Only if you have something the other end that converts it back into its native protocol, which is probably not available.  Alternatively tunnel the SMTP connection through OpenVPN over HTTP but either way you still need another host on the Internet somewhere.